# How to bind List of List in jsf datatable

Tags: jsf, select, datatable

Hi I have a variable like

```
List<List<MyObject>> x = new ArrayList<List<MyObject>>();
```

I wanted this bind to a datatable in jsf which contains select

```
<datatable>
   <column>
      <Select/>
   </column>
</datatable>
```

Is this possible in jsf

Code: 
view.xhtml

```
<h:dataTable id="i1" value="#{bean.listoflist}" var="list1">
  <h:column>
    <h:selectOneListbox value="#{bean.somestring}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{list1.?}" var="any" itemValue="#{any.??}/>"
    </h:selectOneListbox> 
  </h:column>                    
</h:dataTable>`
```

Bean.java (name = "bean")

```
public class Bean implements Serializable
{
  List<List<MyObject>> listoflist = new ArrayList<List<MyObject>>()

 //--------------Getters and Setter
}
```

MyObject.java

```
 public class MyObject
 {
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
   //---------------getter and setter
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem properly, you want to make a datatable of select elements whose options come form the nested list of your model. If yes, here is the solution:

- prepare an array of selected elements per the size of the outer list;
- have a converter for your model object;
- fill the UI components accordingly.

Below you may find a working example:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.listOfLists}" var="list" binding="#{table}" >
    <h:column>
        <h:selectOneListbox value="#{bean.selection[table.rowIndex]}" converter="myObjectConverter" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{list}" var="obj" itemValue="#{obj}" itemLabel="#{obj.s1}" />
       </h:selectOneListbox> 
   </h:column>                    
</h:dataTable>
```

with

```
MyObject[] selection = new MyObject[listOfLists.size()];
```